# Using String to refer to different types of values in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, object

What I'm trying to achieve is something like an array[1] with strings of names of variables and array[2] with generated values for those variables. The variables will be of type char, bool, int, float.

*End goal is to have a list or an array that I can search by a string and get an index to a value that can be of different types. What is the proper way of doing this? Am I looking at the problem from the wrong angle?* **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: It might help to tag this with the specific language you are using.

Comment: As stated it kind of sounds like you describe a `Dictionary` type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0

Comment: `Dictionary<string, object>` should do the job nicely. You can access it using `myDict["abc"]` and get an `object` which you can cast to the desired type.

Comment: You could also approach this using a list of `Tuple` but since `Tuple` tend to be immutable, the comments recommending dictionary have my vote.

Comment: Oh! That's perfect! Didn't know about `Dictionary` Thank you so much!